# Firebase sending entire database on FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged instead of changed data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to listen to any changes made in any children in the Firebase Database. I do the following (in viewDidLoad) which sends me the entire database instead of sending me just the changed child node.

```
var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
self.ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {(snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
            })
```

The positive is that it does get called every time the database values are changed. But the negative is that instead of sending just that affected node, it returns me all the nodes with the updated node which isn't what I want.
Am I calling the right listener or this is unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior: if you register a value observer on a specific node, the block will be triggered with the value of that node whenever there are changes.

If you want to be informed of changes in a lower level in your JSON tree, you should add the observer on that level in the tree.

Comment: I got the hint. I did ref.child("cluster").observe{} and it worked. Now it only sends the changed child node.

Comment: what if you want to capture a change two levels down in the JSON chain but there are several alternative branches?  Is it possible to enter some sort of wild card instead of specifying an exact branch like .child("cluster")?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me (Objective C)  `[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"/chat_server"];`

```
self.refGrito = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"/chat_server"];

    [self.refGrito
     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged
     withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

         NSLog(@"EVENT CHILD CHANGED FOR GRITO : %@ : %@",[snapshot key], snapshot.value);
         [self configureFirebaseProfile:snapshot];

     }];
```